# How many users can add on user group in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, gmail, gmail-api

I want to open my Google Analytics to many students.

How many users can I add as Google Analytics user group in free version? (email numbers)

I wish it were infinite, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this type of problem even in large account, the documentation doesn't mention it, so I'd say that should be no specified limits.